# Without using the mouse, how do I trigger 'Print' in Gmail (using Google Chrome on the Mac)?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, chrome-extensions

Gmail has keyboard shortcuts for seemingly *everything* (including features I’ve never even used or heard of), but there appears to be no keyboard shortcut to *print*.

It also does not seem possible to make a *custom* keyboard shortcut to select “Print” either.

So far the closest that I’ve come is discovering that when a new message is loaded, I can press ⇧Tab *twice* to select the “Print” icon, and then press `Enter` to trigger it. But this completely fails if you have done almost anything after opening the message such as selecting some text, etc. So it is not reliable enough to be useful.

I’m hoping that someone either knows some JavaScript magic or perhaps there is a Google Chrome extension out there which might make this possible.

*(After this many years of Gmail being around, I have to assume the lack of a keyboard shortcut for printing is intentional. Perhaps someone at Google thinks we ought to be living paperless lifestyles, or they figure if you keep all of your email in Gmail rather than printing them to PDF then you’ll use Gmail more. However, I suppose the ‘why’ really isn’t all that important, but it **does** seem like a strange oversight. At least to me.)*

---

**Update:**

I guess I should have been explicitly stated that neither `⌘P` nor `File » Print` will work.

That's why Gmail has its own print icon which opens the message in its own window. Otherwise Chrome tries to print out the sidebar and everything else around the message and you won't even see the main message as part of the printed page or PDF.

Comment: Does pressing **⌘P** work? As in: **Chrome** > **File** > **Print… ⌘P**

Comment: Command & p works in every application I have used on a mac...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way that I triggered the **Print** *sheet* in **Gmail** within **Google Chrome** using a ***keyboard shortcut***:

Doing this on **macOS High Sierra**<sup>1</sup>, in **Automator**, create a new *Service*.<sup>1</sup>

Set **Service receives**<sup>1</sup> `no input` **in** `Google Chrome`

Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the *default code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to execute front window's active tab ¬
    javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-JN L3')[2].click();"
```

Save the *Service* as, e.g.: **Google Chrome Gmail Print**

<sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave**, and later, an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*. There are also other minor nomenclature differences but they should be more obvious when comparing them to pre-macOS Mojave Automator workflows.</sub>

[image: Automator Service]

Assign the *Service* a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

I assigned **⌃⌘P** to the e.g. **Google Chrome Gmail Print** *Service*.

Now in **Gmail**, within **Google Chrome**, having an email opened showing the **print** icon, as shown circled in red in the first image below, and I press **⌃⌘P** the **Gmail Print** *sheet*, as shown in the second image below, is revealed.

---

[image: Gmail - Opened Email]

<sub>Note that in the **standard view**, as shown in the **Gmail** image above, there are four `ElementsByClassName` with `T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-JN L3` as the *class name*. Index `[0]` and `[1]` are used by the *Collapse all* icon or *Expand all* icon that will show, when applicable, to the left of the *Print all* icon `[2]` and index `[3]` is used for the *In new window* icon to the right of the *Print all* icon.</sub>

[image: Gmail Print sheet]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUlSX.png) *statement* and [**error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBrhu.png) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSAT1.png). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>